# Dynamically create nested javascript objects with the same key but different values from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Need help figuring this out..
I want to create nested Javascript Object dynamically..

I have got a key, which has multiple values that needs to be nested per value in an array.
For example:

```
{
    "name": [{
        "desc": "A",
        "age": 26,
        "name": [{
            "desc": "B",
            "age": 12,
            "name": [{
                "desc": "C",
                "age": 48
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

So far i have this:

```js
var data = [[{desc:"A", age:26}], [{desc:"B", age:12}], [{desc:"C", age:48}]]
const name = "name"
var json = {};
var current = json;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    current[name] = data[i];
    current = current[name];
}


console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
```

Which only returns the first item in the data array.

```
{
    "name": [{
        "desc": "A",
        "age": 26
    }]
}
```

Comment: There's no [JSON](http://json.org) in your question. `json` contains a regular object (hence the name of the variable is wrong). And [there's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: Do you want to add a name property to each array,which would contains the next object in the array ?

Comment: Just be careful, JSON Object != JavaScript Object. They share a lot of similar properties, but one is a language-agnostic data standard and the other is how JavaScript deals with data.

Comment: Ahh, my bad guys, editing my question..

Comment: @Nicolas yes, that is correct! the key for each object is same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code does what you want:

```js
var data = [[{desc:"A", age:26}], [{desc:"B", age:12}], [{desc:"C", age:48}]]
const value = data.reverse().reduce((acc, item) => {
    return [{
        ...item[0],
        name: acc
    }]
});

console.log(value);
```

Though if you just had an array of objects instead of an array of arrays containing objects this would be slightly easier:

```
var data = [{desc:"A", age:26}, {desc:"B", age:12}, {desc:"C", age:48}]
data.reverse().reduce((acc, item) => {
    return [{
        ...item,
        name: acc
    }]
});
```

Comment: I've tested your solution and you might want to check out the last children created, it creates an array rather than an object. I'm not sure that's what OP wants.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I didn't notice that - now this should be what was asked for.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what `...item` and `acc` is and how they work?

Comment: @WojciechDynus Very interesting..can you please explain?

Comment: Ok, so the idea overall is to start from the deepest point (C in our case) and go up creating objects containing item's properties and name property with previous (deeper) object as a value. That's why there is reverse at the beginning. Next I use reduce function which is beet described here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce. In my case acc stands for the accumulator. So with the reduce I "iterate" over the array and create proper objects using spread operator (...). I encourage you to play around with reduce and spread operator

Comment: To understand all the concepts best:-)

Comment: I don't understand how each sub array is appended to same array with just typing `return { ...item, name:acc }`

Comment: There is a bug in this code - it should be `return [{...item, name: acc}]`. Nicolas pointed me that so I fixed the first code but forgot to also fix the second one. Just edited my response so all should be fine now

Answer (score 1):

You need to use recursion in this case since your are creating children. 
In this code, we reduce the size of the array by removing the first element and passing it back to the same function

```js
var data = [
  [{desc:"A", age:26}],
  [{desc:"B", age:12}],
  [{desc:"C", age:48}]
]

function recursivelyAssignData(array) {
  // we get the current element, to assign it a property "name", 
  const currentElement = array[0][0]
  // we remove the first element, so it wont be pass to subsequent call of the function.
  array.shift();
  // if this is the last element, we don't want to assign the property "name" to it.
  return array.length >= 1 ? Object.assign(currentElement, {
    // we assign the value of same function, but with a different array.
    name: recursivelyAssignData(array),
  }) : currentElement;
}


const result = {request: recursivelyAssignData(data)};
console.log('results:', result , 'json:', JSON.stringify(result ));
```

**P.S**
Recursion might not be the most intuitive thing in the world, if you have trouble understand it, please ask question.

Comment: Ahh, i see Thank you! I do however, want to array itself to be assigned to the name key. I am going to give it a shot using your code above. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. Since the values are inserted as first item in an array, use index `0` to access them.

```js
const data = [[{desc:"A", age:26}], [{desc:"B", age:12}], [{desc:"C", age:48}]];
const name = "name";
let result = {
  [name]: data[0]
};
let obj = result;

for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
  let current = obj[name][0];
  current[name] = data[i];
  obj = current;
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks @Nikhil! this is such a simple way to achieve what i am looking for.

Comment: That's right @Jay. You're welcome. I'm glad it helped.